# Merging data frames with different sample frequency

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames - one which is an hourly data set (dfa) and one which has measurements per day (dfb) at the same hour each day (15:29:05) (see below for examples with 2 days)

I want to merge these data frames so that i keep all the hourly data and the daily joins aligning with the correct hour and when there is no data for the other hours of the day it fills with NA's

Simply applying merge just cuts it to the the daily data and so I loose all the hourly information:

```
 dfc <- merge(dfa, dfb, by = "datetime")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

e.g. for two days:

```
#hourly
dfa <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1466231345, 1466234945, 
 1466238545, 1466242145, 1466245745, 1466249345, 1466252945, 1466256545, 
 1466260145, 1466263745, 1466267345, 1466270945, 1466274545, 1466278145, 
 1466281745, 1466285345, 1466288945, 1466292545, 1466296145, 1466299745, 
 1466303345, 1466306945, 1466310545, 1466314145, 1466317745, 1466321345, 
 1466324945, 1466328545, 1466332145, 1466335745, 1466339345, 1466342945, 
 1466346545, 1466350145, 1466353745, 1466357345, 1466360945, 1466364545, 
 1466368145, 1466371745, 1466375345, 1466378945, 1466382545, 1466386145, 
 1466389745, 1466393345, 1466396945, 1466400545), class = c("POSIXct", 
 "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), DFQ1 = c(0.408025, 0.4355833335, 
  0.68485, 0.650875, 0.5307833335, 0.509775, 0.5273135595, 0.5763083335, 
  0.4954, 0.444308333, 0.4048083335, 0.419475, 0.35105, 0.2740416665, 
  0.3038666665, 0.351774317, 0.306025, 0.3183916665, 0.249175, 
  0.268133333, 0.3285083335, 0.2807666665, 0.351633333, 0.374516667, 
 0.3763, 0.3806583335, 0.366675, 0.411133333, 0.433291667, 0.408225, 
 0.3812, 0.380358333, 0.3557166665, 0.3701, 0.400788842, 0.396833333, 
 0.362991667, 0.3790083335, 0.3631666665, 0.367041667, 0.3899583335, 
  0.360658333, 0.359675, 0.356358333, 0.3864083335, 0.3965083335, 
  0.3901166665, 0.403976695)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -48L))

 #daily
 dfb <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1466263745, 1466350145), class 
= c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Tchl = c(0.1265, 0.1503), TCSE = structure(c(12L, 
 9L), .Label = c("", "#DIV/0!", "0.000", "0.001", "0.002", "0.003", 
"0.004", "0.005", "0.007", "0.008", "0.009", "0.010", "0.011", 
"0.012", "0.013", "0.015", "0.021", "0.026", "0.027", "CB2016", 
"Std error"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -2L))
```

Comment: `merge(dfa, dfb, by = "datetime", all = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
dfc <- merge(dfa, dfb, by = "datetime", all.x = TRUE)

#               datetime      DFQ1   Tchl  TCSE 
# 1  2016-06-18 06:29:05 0.4080250     NA  <NA>
# 2  2016-06-18 07:29:05 0.4355833     NA  <NA>
# 3  2016-06-18 08:29:05 0.6848500     NA  <NA>
# 4  2016-06-18 09:29:05 0.6508750     NA  <NA>
# 5  2016-06-18 10:29:05 0.5307833     NA  <NA>
# 6  2016-06-18 11:29:05 0.5097750     NA  <NA>
# 7  2016-06-18 12:29:05 0.5273136     NA  <NA>
# 8  2016-06-18 13:29:05 0.5763083     NA  <NA>
# 9  2016-06-18 14:29:05 0.4954000     NA  <NA>
# 10 2016-06-18 15:29:05 0.4443083 0.1265 0.010
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks - that was easy!

Answer (score 1):

Or a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
dfc <- left_join(dfa, dfb, by="datetime")

#> head(dfc,10)
#              datetime      DFQ1   Tchl  TCSE
#1  2016-06-18 06:29:05 0.4080250     NA  <NA>
#2  2016-06-18 07:29:05 0.4355833     NA  <NA>
#3  2016-06-18 08:29:05 0.6848500     NA  <NA>
#4  2016-06-18 09:29:05 0.6508750     NA  <NA>
#5  2016-06-18 10:29:05 0.5307833     NA  <NA>
#6  2016-06-18 11:29:05 0.5097750     NA  <NA>
#7  2016-06-18 12:29:05 0.5273136     NA  <NA>
#8  2016-06-18 13:29:05 0.5763083     NA  <NA>
#9  2016-06-18 14:29:05 0.4954000     NA  <NA>
#10 2016-06-18 15:29:05 0.4443083 0.1265 0.010
```